# Cannot unbox as Int

Tags: c#, parameters, unboxing

I have this sql parameter im getting the cant unbox as int error

```
returnValue = (int)cmdUpdateCreatedOn.Parameters["@intcount"].Value;
```

return value is declared as int returnValue = 0
and my parameter is also declared as int, and it is getting the rowcount of rows updated.
I've tried different converting syntax none seem to work.

MY SP is

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[UpdateStation]
@intcount int output AS 
select StationaryName into #stname from Stationaries where Authorized = 0 
select * from #stname 
Update Stationaries Set  Authorized = 1 where Authorized = 0 set @intcount =   @@rowcount
```

Comment: Look at the value in the debugger.  What is the value?  What is its type?  My money's on the value either being a nullable int or actually being `null`, but regardless of the issue, it's trivial to solve.

Comment: What *exact* error are you getting?

Comment: in the debugger its value is an int, and it says, cannot unbox 'cmdUpdateCreatedOn.Parameters["@intcount"].Value' as an int

Comment: Try this and tell us what the value of `type` is: `var type = cmdUpdateCreatedOn.Parameters["@intcount"].Value.GetType();`

Comment: my returnValue is an int but it saying that the expression is an object

Comment: Are you sure you're getting an `int` back from the database? Unboxing requires you to unbox to the original type it was boxed from before casting it to the desired type. Is there a chance you boxed it, or the DB is boxing, to a different value type?

Comment: this is my stored procedure

Comment: ALTER Procedure [dbo].[UpdateStation]
"atsign"intcount int output
AS 
select StationaryName into #stname from Stationaries where Authorized = 0
select * from #stname
Update Stationaries
Set 
Authorized = 1
where Authorized = 0
set "atsign"intcount = "atsign""atsign"rowcount

Comment: u better put that as an update in your question csharper.

Comment: what is your rowcount type? @@rowcount?

Comment: Have a look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771476/c-sharp-issues-with-boxing-unboxing-typecasting-ints-i-dont-understand

The question is: is the returned value really an Int32? May be some other int?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue.

The INT being returned in stored procedure is of type 'SHORT'. I do not know why.

Cannot cast ..."@SubjectID"... (which has an actual type of 'short') to 'string'.

**Solution:**
 1. Unbox to 'SHORT' in c# OR 

 2. Use Convert.ToInt32 in c#.