# Runtime Type Checking and Unboxing

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion

This code is compiled.

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        object obj = 0; 
        long x = (long) obj; 
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

In run-time it throws this Unhandled Exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to
>   destination type.
>   at Program.Main () [0x00000] in :0
>   [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidCastException: Cannot
>   cast from source type to destination type.
>   at Program.Main () [0x00000] in :0

The following chunk is compiled and run correctly.

```
static void Main()
    {
        object obj = 0; 
        long x = (int) obj; 
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
```

> > 0

What's going on?

Comment: Because the integer literal `0` is an `int`. You can only unbox a boxed value type to its original type. See [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085097/why-cant-i-unbox-an-int-as-a-decimal) and [C# - Issues with boxing / unboxing / typecasting ints. I don't understand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771476/c-sharp-issues-with-boxing-unboxing-typecasting-ints-i-dont-understand).

Comment: try with `object obj = 0L;`

Comment: @CodeCaster so the exception is thrown during the unboxing operation?

Comment: I was hoping you would know, because you have the code and can attach a debugger. :) But yeah, it is thrown during unboxing.